# sort table records in descending order - symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a table of records in the db where the last inserted record is the last in the table row of records. In my symfony application I have a snippet that fetches data from the db but the last inserted record is the last in the view when the result is iterated through. Here is the snippet

**EDITED**

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('myBundle:Images')->findAll();
```

How can I sort the above doctrine snippet in descending order whereby the last inserted becomes the first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have id column

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('myBundle:Images')->findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second param is for order:

```
$messages = $em->getRepository("myBundle:Comments")->findBy(
    array(
        "imagefk" => $image
    ),
    array('id' => 'DESC')
);
```

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L177